# How can I "divide" words with regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex

I have a sentence in which every token has a `/` in it. I want to just print what I have before the slash.

What I have now is basic:

```
text = less/RBR.....
return re.findall(r'\b(\S+)\b', text)
```

This obviously just prints the text, how do I cut off the words before the `/`?

Comment: So, you have multiple "words" in a string, something like nltk output, right? [`re.findall(r'\b(?<!/)\w[^/]*', text)`](https://regex101.com/r/aI8oN6/1) should help.

Comment: So you want of every word that contains a slash, all characters before the slash. That would be for the input string `match/this but nothing here but another/one` you would want `match` and `another`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want all characters before the slash out of every word that contains a slash. This would mean e.g. for the input string `match/this but nothing here but another/one` you would want the results `match` and `another`.

---

#### With regex:

```
import re
result = re.findall(r"\b(\w*?)/\w*?\b", my_string)
print(result)
```

#### Without regex:

```
result = [word.split("/")[0] for word in my_string.split()]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple and straight-forward:

```
rx = r'^[^/]+'
# anchor it to the beginning
# the class says: match everything not a forward slash as many times as possible
```

In `Python` this would be:

```
import re
text = "less/RBR....."
print re.match(r'[^/]+', text)
```

As this is an object, you'd probably like to print it out, like so:

```
print re.match(r'[^/]+', text).group(0)
# less
```

Answer (score 1):

This should also work

```
\b([^\s/]+)(?=/)\b
```

*Python Code*

```
p = re.compile(r'\b([^\s/]+)(?=/)\b')
test_str = "less/RBR/...."

print(re.findall(p, test_str))
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/DbSwip)**